# How to return Firebase's rejected promise in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to return some data from the Rejected function of a Firebase promise in Angular to use in $routeChangeError. For some reason, the console.error(data) works, but the next line return data doesn't.

This is my code:

```js
angular.module('campaignsHub.dashboard', ['ngRoute'])
  .run(["$rootScope", "$location", "$route",
    function($rootScope, $location, $route) {

      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {

        // This works if I use return authService.auth.$requireAuth(); and nothing else
        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
          $location.path("/login");
        }

      });

    }
  ])

.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
      resolve: {

        "currentAuth": ["authService",
          function(authService) {
            authService.auth.$requireAuth().then(function(data) {
              // RESOLVED
              authService.GetCurrentUser().then(function(userData) {
                return userData; // This works if user is logged in
              })
            }, function(data) {
              // REJECTED
              console.error(data); // This part works - returns AUTH_REQUIRED if user is not logged in
              return data; // This part doesn't as it should be picked up by the .run() method
            });
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a promise to work properly you have to return the promise from the function. Once the promise is resolved the calle get the resolved data which it can use to further process.

So you definitely need `return` statement for your authService inside resolve.

Change this

```
function(authService) {
            authService.auth.$requireAuth().then(function(data) {
              // RESOLVED
              authService.GetCurrentUser().then(function(userData) {
                return userData; // This works if user is logged in
              })
            }, function(data) {
              // REJECTED
              console.error(data); // This part works - returns AUTH_REQUIRED if user is not logged in
              return data; // This part doesn't as it should be picked up by the .run() method
            });
          }
```

to

```
function(authService) {
            return authService.auth.$requireAuth().then(function(data) {
              // RESOLVED
              authService.GetCurrentUser().then(function(userData) {
                return userData; // This works if user is logged in
              })
            }, function(data) {
              // REJECTED
              console.error(data); // This part works - returns AUTH_REQUIRED if user is not logged in
              return data; // This part doesn't as it should be picked up by the .run() method
            });
          }
```

Comment: Hi Shankar, 

Thanks for your answer! The added return definitely works in returning my data, but the resolve doesn't fail if the user is not logged in. If I just use 'return authService.auth.$requireAuth()', the resolve returns "AUTH_REQUIRED" and the $routeChangeError triggers, redirecting the user to the login page - that's the behaviour I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to find a solution. To get it working, I expanded Shankar's solution and returned every promise in my resolve method. So now, it looks like this:

```js
resolve: {
  "currentAuth": ["authService",
    function(authService) {
      return authService.auth.$requireAuth().then(function(data) {
        // RESOLVED
        return authService.GetCurrentUser().then(function(userData) {
          return userData;
        })
      }, function(data) {
        // REJECTED
        throw data;
      });
    }
  ]
}
```